# How can I access custom IdentityUser data (Img Name) inside the LoginPartial (.Net Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

I was wondering how I can display the custom data I've used to extend the IdentityUser.

By default the loginpartial displays User.Identity.Name (which is actually an e-mail address), I would like to display the user's fullname and display an user image with it. It calls User.Identity.Name from interface IIdentity

```
    namespace System.Security.Principal
{ 
    public interface IIdentity
    {   
        string AuthenticationType { get; }
        bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
        string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

I can't change this file though. This is my class extending the identityuser

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser() : base() { } 
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    public string Tussenvoegsel { get; set; }
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Gebruikersnummer { get; set; }
    public string ImgNaam { get; set; }
}
```

in the partial view I call for this model class aswell:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Now my question is, how can I retreive string ImgNaam inside of my partial view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better to store the information you need in Claims ([you can read this post about it](https://korzh.com/blogs/dotnet-stories/add-extra-user-claims-aspnet-core-webapp)).

But you also can get information using `UserManager`.

You can use `User` variable which has `ClaimsPrincipal` type to get the whole user from UserManager using the following code:

```cs
@
{
     var activeUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
}
```

After this, you can use this variable:

```html
   <img src="@activeUser.ImgNaam">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@{
   ApplicationUser loggedInUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User); // Here `User` is the claim principal
   var imgNaam= loggedInUser.ImgNaam;
}
```